# How To Abort Axios GET Request While State Is Updating?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, get, axios

I'm making multiple async GET requests with different parameters to an API on single form submit and updating the state after each request.

The only problem is when submitting the form while the previous request is not finished yet. (i.e submit the form when the previous request still loading). Although I empty the state at the beginning on form submit, the state will be filled with a mixture of previous request and new request. This is due to the previous request still running.

I tried axios cancellation but as the state is constantly updating, It's not clear for me how to use componentDidUpdate(), or another method, to abort the request.

```
<form onSubmit={searchFlights}>


searchFlights = async e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({ flights: []});

   //Dummy Data: array of different parameters
    onDates = [1,2,3,4];
```

```
// Fetch result for each Day
    for (let i = 0; i < onDates.length; i++) {
      let onDate = onDates[i];

      const res = await axios.get(
        `API/?date_from=${onDate}`
      );
      const flightResult = res.data.data[0];

      this.setState({
        flights: [...this.state.flights, flightResult]
      }); //note the state is updating after each loop
   
    }
```

when the form was submitted again while previous request is running, I want it to stop fetching the previous request, clear the state and get ONLY the new request

Answer (score 0):

setState is asynchronous and you'll get the new state in the next render cycle. So you are doing it wrong. Why not push the axios results into an array and set the state of the flights after the loop, from the array?

```
<form onSubmit={searchFlights}>


searchFlights = async e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const flights =[];

   //Dummy Data: array of different parameters
    onDates = [1,2,3,4];
```

```
  // Fetch result for each Day
    for (let i = 0; i < onDates.length; i++) {
      let onDate = onDates[i];

      const res = await axios.get(
        `API/?date_from=${onDate}`
      );
      const flightResult = res.data.data[0];

    flights.push[flightResult]
    }
    this.setState({flights});
```

Comment: It still does not solve the issue. If I submit a form and while thats loading submit another form, it will show the result for first request and once the second request is done it will show that. I need a way to stop the get request and start a new one if form submission was corrupted

Comment: Oh I see. You want the first submit to not go through if you do another submit? I've no idea in that regard. I assume the first submit will go through, since it will already be in the call stack.